# Conditional Regression in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, regression

I am trying to build a conditional regression where a user can enter a specific range of years and the regression formula will only consider the years within that specified range. Ultimately, I am interested in retrieving one of the parameters from the logest function. I know how to manually reference the rows I am interested in, but would like to set this up dynamically. Below is an example of the formula I tried using which did not work:

```
=INDEX(LOGEST(--($C$2:$C$21>=B24)*($C$2:$C$21<=C24)*($D$2:$D$21),--($C$2:$C$21>=B24)*($C$2:$C$21<=C24)*($C$2:$C$21),1),1)-1
```

Where C is the range of years in the data and D is the range of amounts by year. Below is sample data with the expected result for each year range. The expected result for the 2003 - 2021 period was achieved with the following formula:

```
=INDEX(LOGEST($D$2:$D$20,$C$2:$C$20,1),1)-1
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel while allowing multiple ranges to be evaluated at once as in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 2 INDEX/MATCH to return the correct range:

```
=INDEX(LOGEST(
    INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(B24,$C:$C,0)):INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(C24,$C:$C,0)),
    INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(B24,$C:$C,0)):INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(C24,$C:$C,0)),
    1),1)-1
```